# Create Native Gnome Menus

Tags: gnome, python

How does one use gnome native elements? For example empathy can:

- Create pop-ups with text-boxes and pictures.
- Right clicking on the top-left icon produces a menu.
- The system tray

  - The system tray icon also has a "gnome-type?" pop-up when left clicked which 
    looks  and acts better then other apps with system tray icons.

Is there a tool kit or something? I am particularity interested in python bindings but any info is helpful. It may without saying but this is Gnome 3.

EDIT: These features can be found in most gnome apps, not just empathy.

Here's a decent [example](http://cdn-static.zdnet.com/i/story/60/05/009347/gnome3.png).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never used Empathy, but since it's a Gnome app, it'll use GTK as toolkit. You examples sound really specific, so they will create very specific, custom widgets. Check out their sourcecode for more information.

Comment: @Timo sorry to make the examples so specific, there are only a few things that do this fully. Pithos is a good example of notifications since it expands, shows pictures, does stuff on left click, ect. Network errors in the system tray have nice left-click pop-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In particular, Gnome3 is written with GTK+3. You can find a general tutorial on using [GTK+ 3 with Python](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Also take a look specifically on [GNOME Developer Center](https://developer.gnome.org/). In particular you may be interested in the [Python Bindings](https://developer.gnome.org/references#python-bindings).

For further, more specific programming questions, I recommend using [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as a resource for asking questions, a sister site to AskUbuntu.